# how to cache html5 File object?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of of `File` objects and I wanna keep them on the clients browser so I can interact with it in the background while the user happily browse through the site.

My question is, what's the best place to store this array (client side)? I need to store them somewhere because right now its just on a variable, if user navigates to other pages of the site the array will get lost.

Comment: You need to save the file in the [sandboxed filesystem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File_API/File_System_API)

Comment: Also see the [MDN DOM Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) entry.

Comment: Looks like localstorage is the way to go, thanks guys.

Comment: @Marconi localstorage stores strings only and has 5mb limit. But it's better supported.

Comment: @Esailija yes I just tried it, so this won't work since I really need the File object and serializing is not an option since it will easily exhaust 5mb. :/